# Exception Handling Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, exception

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas
import pymysql
from datetime import datetime
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
try:
    driver.maximize_window()
except:
    print("windows already maximized")

driver.get("https:www.google.com")
for i in range(1,11):
  for j in range (1,41): 
     try:
       driver.find_element_by_id("all-checkbox").click()
       driver.find_element_by_id("...").click()
       driver.find_element_by_id("....").click()
       .....
       .....
       .....
     except Exception as e:
        print(type(e))  #Print Result added below
        print(e)        #Print Result added Below
```

Print result of type(e) and e

```
type(e): <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>
e:   Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="all-checkbox"]"}
      (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.72)
```

This is the actual exception:

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3fafa99d1578> in <module>
     14 
     15 driver.get("https:www.google.com")
---> 16 driver.find_element_by_id("all-checkbox").click()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element_by_id(self, id_)
    358             element = driver.find_element_by_id('foo')
    359         """
--> 360         return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
    361 
    362     def find_elements_by_id(self, id_):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    974                 by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
--> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
    978             'value': value})['value']

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="all-checkbox"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.72)
```

There will be same type of exception raised with differend method and selector. Now I want to add some if-else statement on that error object.Something like:

```
if (e.method=="css selector" && e.selector=="[id = "all-checkbox"]") {
       ..../Some Logic;
       break;
            }
else {continue;}
```

How can I do above??
And if anyone has a link to official docs of selenium error handling Please share.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the use case

Comment: driver.find().click() will raise NoSuchElementException for different elements on webage.I have already added explicit and implicit wait.But still there are chances  NoSuchElementException can be raised.Now i want to execute different set of code depending on  element on which NoSuchElementException was raised.Also edited source code to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: I dont know which element will raise exception and when during the execution of both loops.But I know for sure that exception will be raised.So i need a way to filter the exceptions.And I know one of the solutions is to try/catch on every individual element but i only have to filter for three elements and rest can go in else statement.So I would like to avoid that solution if possible

Comment: Your URL is not valid. Is that the actual URL you are using?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.